# Reading data corresponding to a specific ID from the database and passing the data to an API

Tags: python, django, database, backend

I am trying to fetch data from a database table named "orders_address" by specifying the required ID in the request body and I expect to receive the row for this specific ID along with an API result in the response. However, I can't get fetch the data for this specific ID from the database. I am using DJANGO.

I am applying this request body:

```
{
    "orders": [1]
}
```

and my response results is:

```
{"error": "No orders found for the given order IDs."}
```

Here is my route_optimization.py script which does the function needed:

```
import requests
from django.http import JsonResponse
from orders.models import Order
import configparser
import json

# Read configuration file
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('config.ini')

# Get Nextbillion.ai API key from config
NB_API_KEY = config['API_KEYS']['NB_API_KEY']

def optimize_route(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        try:
            data = json.loads(request.body)
            order_ids = data.get('orders', [])

            print("Received order IDs:", order_ids)  # Debugging statement

            # Fetch orders from the database based on order IDs
            orders = Order.objects.filter(id__in=order_ids)
            print("Orders:", orders)  # Debugging statement

            # Ensure that orders are retrieved
            if not orders:
                return JsonResponse({'error': 'No orders found for the given order IDs.'})

            # Construct list of delivery locations for Nextbillion.ai API payload
            delivery_locations = [
                {"latitude": order.address.latitude, "longitude": order.address.longitude}
                for order in orders
            ]

            # Static starting point for vehicles
            starting_point = {"latitude": 24.5678, "longitude": 45.6789}

            # Optimize route using dynamically fetched delivery locations
            optimized_route = optimize_route_with_nextbillion(NB_API_KEY, starting_point, delivery_locations)

            return JsonResponse({'message': 'Route optimized successfully', 'optimized_route': optimized_route})

        except Exception as e:
            return JsonResponse({'error': str(e)})

    else:
        return JsonResponse({'error': 'Only POST requests are allowed.'})

def optimize_route_with_nextbillion(nb_api_key, starting_point, delivery_locations):
    # Nextbillion.ai route optimization API endpoint
    endpoint = f"https://api.nextbillion.io/optimization/v2?key={nb_api_key}"

    # Define the payload for route optimization
    payload = {
        "description": "Optimization with Dynamic Delivery Locations",
        "locations": {
            "id": 1,
            "location": [f"{location['latitude']},{location['longitude']}" for location in delivery_locations]
        },
        "jobs": [],
        "vehicles": [
            {"id": 1, "start_index": 0, "end_index": 0, "capacity": [46], "time_window": [1688110200, 1688140800], "skills": [2, 3]}
        ],
        "shipments": []
    }

    # Add starting point for vehicles
    payload["locations"]["location"].insert(0, f"{starting_point['latitude']},{starting_point['longitude']}")

    # Add delivery jobs
    for i, location in enumerate(delivery_locations, start=1):
        payload["jobs"].append({
            "id": i,
            "location_index": i,  # Adjust index to match delivery location index
            "service": 300,
            "delivery": [i],  # Specifying as delivery job
            "time_windows": [[1688112000, 1688119200]]
        })

    # Check if any jobs are present
    if not payload["jobs"]:
        raise ValueError("No jobs specified for processing.")

    # Make POST request to Nextbillion.ai API
    headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    response = requests.post(endpoint, json=payload, headers=headers)

    if response.status_code == 200:
        # Route optimization successful
        optimized_route = response.json()
        print("Optimized route:", optimized_route)
        return optimized_route
    else:
        # Route optimization failed
        print("Failed to optimize route. Status code:", response.status_code)
        print("Response content:", response.content.decode('utf-8'))
        raise ValueError(f"Nextbillion.ai API error: {response.text}")
```

My terminal output (based on debug print statements is the following:

Received order IDs: [1]
Orders: <QuerySet []>
[31/Jan/2024 20:29:35] "POST /route_optimization/optimize_route/ HTTP/1.1" 200 53

So it means that there is a row with ID "1" available in the database, however it is not reading / fetching the data of this row and writing it to my API workload.

I assume my issue lies with reading / writing the data from the database.

My database tables are set into another Django app (orders) and here is the orders/models.py assuming the issue is a tables relationship issue?

```
from django.db import models

class Address(models.Model):
    building_number = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    post_code = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    street_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    latitude = models.FloatField()
    longitude = models.FloatField()
    district = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.building_number} {self.street_name}, {self.city}, {self.post_code}"

    def get_full_address(self):
        return f"{self.building_number} {self.street_name}, {self.city}, {self.post_code}"

class Order(models.Model):
    drop_off_location = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    timestamp_start = models.DateTimeField()
    timestamp_end = models.DateTimeField()
    address = models.ForeignKey(Address, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Order for {self.drop_off_location} ({self.timestamp_start} - {self.timestamp_end})"
```

Here are the data in my database tables:

Here is my orders_address table:

```
id  building_number post_code   city    street_name latitude    longitude   district
1   2522    12244   RIYADH  Khalid Ibn Yazeed Ibn Muawiyah  24.70875674 46.6802742  Al Olaya Dist.
```

Here is my orders_order table:

```
id  drop_off_location   timestamp_start timestamp_end   address_id
1   RHOC2522    00:00.0 00:00.0 1
2   RHOC2522    00:00.0 00:00.0 1
3   RHOC2522    00:00.0 00:00.0 1
```

Comment: The code all looks good. `Received order IDs: [1] Orders: <QuerySet []> ` suggests that an order with id `1` does not exist, but your `orders_order` table output says it does.  Can you run `Order.objects.get(id=1)` at the terminal and ensure a row is returned?